# Cannot read property 'user' of undefined in Angular and Firebase Auth

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication

Working with Firebase for the first time and trying to set up email and Google auth in an Angular (v5) app. Following a tutorial (https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/#Step-5-User-Profile), I get an error:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`

The error is coming from the template:

login.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="auth.user | async; then authenticated else guest">
  <!-- template will replace this div -->
</div>
<!-- User NOT logged in -->
<ng-template #guest>
  <h3>Howdy, GUEST</h3>
  <p>Login to get started...</p>

  <button (click)="auth.googleLogin()">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i> Connect Google
  </button>
</ng-template>
<!-- User logged in -->
<ng-template #authenticated>
  <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
    <h3>Howdy, {{ user.displayName }}</h3>
    <img  [src]="user.photoURL">
    <p>UID: {{ user.uid }}</p>
    <p>Favorite Color: {{ user?.favoriteColor }} </p>
    <button (click)="auth.signOut()">Logout</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

login.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument} from 
'angularfire2/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'

interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  favoriteColor?: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router) {
    //// Get auth data, then get firestore user document || null
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState
      .switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
        } else {
          return Observable.of(null)
        }
      })
  }
  googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }
  private oAuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((credential) => {
        this.updateUserData(credential.user)
      })
  }
  private updateUserData(user) {
    // Sets user data to firestore on login
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = 
    this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const data: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL
    };
    return userRef.set(data)
  }
  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }
}
```

This SO question seems similar but unsure how the answer would apply to my issue: [firebase onAuth() throwing: TypeError cannot read property 'auth' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528532/firebase-onauth-throwing-typeerror-cannot-read-property-auth-of-undefined) and how to fix my problem.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Change `constructor(public authService: AuthService)` to `constructor(public auth: AuthService)`

Comment: Try to use the Elvis operator in all async calls... **ngIf="auth?.user | async; then authenticated else guest"**. This will avoid a lot of runtime errors.

Comment: Try putting your html code where you're calling auth.user inside a block of <ng-template *ngIf="user">.. here access auth.user...</ng-template>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yurzui's solution above solved the issue.

I changed the `constructor(public authService: AuthService)` to `constructor(public auth: AuthService)`.